# Factory method pattern and abstract factory pattern

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, abstract-factory, template-method-pattern

I have a question which has been explained in many ways , but still has not made me clear.

1. What is creating of objects by "Object composition" in terms of abstract factory pattern ?

It seems like both the patterns use inheritance to create objects.

Comment: What are you reading that talks about this?

Comment: The interface of an abstract factory, or a class with a factory method may very well be defined in an interface and therefore does not have to use inheritance to create objects.

Comment: Mr Vaughn, I read this while trying to understand Factory method and abstract factory pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Object composition means the object is composed of something.  It's basically the strategy pattern, making the two objects have a "has-a" relationship, rather than an "is-a" relationship (as with straight inheritance).

Comment: I know that each object in the family of related objects created as part of abstract factory can be created by a factory method. But I did not understand why strategy pattern  comes into picture.